# vscode live-server extension v5.6.1 fails to resolve 'axios' JavaScript import

Tags: javascript, axios, atom-liveserver

I installed axios via npm and when I run the live-server extension it doesn't recognize the axios imports in my .js files. When I use the "import axios from 'axios'" command I get this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"." any ideas?

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "footballstatsil",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A website for football statistics",
  "default": "controller.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel index.html",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "author": "Dror Salomon",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "parcel": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

import example:

```
import axios from "axios";

import {
  API_URL_PLAYERS,
  API_URL_TEAMS,
  API_KEY,
  RAPIDAPI_HOST,
} from "./config.js";

const createOptionsObject = function (url, params) {
  return options = {
    method: "GET",
    url: url,
    params: params,
    headers: {
      "x-rapidapi-host": `${RAPIDAPI_HOST}`,
      "x-rapidapi-key": `${API_KEY}`,
    },
  };
}

export const loadTeams = async function (leagueID, season) {
  try {
    
    const teamOptions = createOptionsObject(API_URL_TEAMS, { league: leagueID, season: season })

    axios.request(teamOptions).then(function (response) {
     
      response.data.response.forEach((el) => {
    
        const teamsMarkup = `
       <li class="dropdown-li"><a class="dropdown-item">${el.team.name}</a></li>`;
       teamsSelector.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', teamsMarkup);

      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't think axios supports ESM imports yet. Either change your imports to commonjs `require()`s or use a module that supports ESM such as node-fetch. If it's client-side, use the built-in `fetch` method

Comment: Sidenote 1: you don't need the Axios library (unless you have very specific needs), browsers have been supporting [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) natively for a while now. Sidenote 2: using `async` without `await` is useless

Comment: Yeah I guess that I`ll use fetch and that's that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well using skypack solved the problem:

```
import axios from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/axios';
```

instead of

```
import axios from 'axios';
```